# Is it safe to use a nuget package to securely hash & salt passwords before saving them into the database?

Tags: c#, hash, passwords, password-protection, bcrypt

Would it be safe to use a library such as this one:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt-Official/ to safely hash the account passwords when a new account registers.

Comment: Do you want to know how secure the Blowfish cipher is?

Comment: I think it's quite secure right?

Comment: Define "safe". What kind of risks do you want to mitigate and/or accept?

Comment: Safe as in, is the hashing algorithm used in such a package implemented in a right manner. As I would be using an external dll to do something which is quite important (hashing passwords), I would like to know if such a package is approved by people.